# Is Select2 trigger("change") a long Ajax event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm noticing in my app that the Select2 `trigger("change")` takes quite a bit of time, i.e. a visible delay happens when I change the value of my dropdown and then issue

`$("#mySelect").val('NewVal').trigger("change")`

to force the control to reflect the new value. The lag is about half-a-second.

My problem is I can't have lags without a Spinner Overlay. All delays must be covered by the Spinner overlay, which means I need to capture the End/Completion of the Select2 Trigger Change.

Can anyone advise if the Select2 Trigger Change is an Ajax operation and whether I should chain it as some kind of `.then()` ? I just need the Spinner to be active while the change event happens...

Comment: Please share more code... I've never noticed that problem

Comment: Yeah it looks like it can be fast... https://jsfiddle.net/L3524ond/